# Flask-SQLAlchemy - a model with many-to-many relationships with two other models

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

Thank you in advance!  I am working on a client relationship management app and am trying to configure the service level agreement models for meetings and calls.  Both of these will share a many-to-many relationship with the model Month which is just the months of the year.  Below is my code and the errors I am getting below that.

```
months = db.Table(
    "months",
    db.Column("month_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("month.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("slacall_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("sla_call.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column(
        "slameeting_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("sla_meeting.id"), primary_key=True
    ),
)


class SLACall(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    per_year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    months = db.relationship(
        "Month",
        secondary=months,
        lazy="subquery",
        backref=db.backref("slacalls", lazy=True),
    )
    relationship_id = db.relationship("Relationship", backref="sla_call", lazy=True)


class SLAMeeting(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    per_year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    months = db.relationship(
        "Month",
        secondary=months,
        lazy="subquery",
        backref=db.backref("slameetings", lazy=True),
    )
    relationship_id = db.relationship("Relationship", backref="sla_meeting", lazy=True)


class Month(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    month_name = db.Column(db.String(9), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

And I am getting the following error when I boot up flask for both SLA models (only one of the errors shown):

> /home/kendall/Python/pm_crm/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py:550: SAWarning: relationship 'Month.slameetings' will copy column month.id to column months.month_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Month.slacalls' (copies month.id to months.month_id), 'SLACall.months' (copies month.id to months.month_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="months,slacalls"' to the 'Month.slameetings' relationship. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/qzyx)

Is this not the correct way to set this up?  Or are multiple many-to-many relationships to a single model not possible?

Thank you again,
Kendall

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? SLACall linked to SLAMeeting and both linked to a month? Or a SLACall to a month and a SLAMeeting to a month?

Comment: Both linked to month.  No relationship between SLACall and SLAMonth,